# Bluetooth Manager Tools

Tags: software-recommendation, bluetooth

What bluetooth tools are available in Ubuntu to configure a bluetooth device. For example changing the frequency it uses, detecting and showing all bluetooth devices connected to the PC and any other settings that will help configure a bluetooth device.

For the moment I have 2 wireless bluetooth mice, 1 bluetooth keyboard and one bluetooth dongle so that other cellphones can connect to it and share mp3, images and other phone stuff.

`dmesg` tells me when I connect the mice and keyboard and they were detected and configure but there is no GUI applicacion to manage them and configure maybe some additional settings. The only bluetooth device I can actually configure is the dongle to connect to a cellphones.

Is there any bluetooth managers (GUI Based but terminal would work also) that I can use to configure the mice, keyboard and any other bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having installed the [bluez-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bluez-utils) [image: Install bluez-utils] we have access to some nice command line tools to show and manage bluetooth devices:

```
hciconfig --all # shows all known devices
hcitool scan # shows devices that are connected
sdptool browse # shows available services on the remote device
```

Answer (score 0):

Bluewho? You can install it from the Software Center.It's GUI Bluetooth application.

Comment: Very cool app actually. Nice features. But I am looking for one that can show me the bluetooth mice and keyboard I have connected. There actually show as 2.4Ghz Wireless Mouse and Keyboard in dmesg but am almost sure they are bluetooth because of the 10M max distance.