# Bluetooth manager for sending/receiving files?

Tags: software-recommendation, bluetooth, gui, blueman

From the Bluetooth managers, I know of `blueman` (which I can't use because of a known bug whereas it [fails to receive files](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/84)) and `gnome-bluetooth` (which I'd rather not install because of the number of unnecessary dependencies).

Are there any other GUI Bluetooth Managers out there? I'm mostly interested in sending/receiving files to and from other Bluetooth devices...

PS From the looks of it, this is NOT a duplicate of [Bluetooth Manager Tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78119/bluetooth-manager-tools). And I'm looking for tools that would go well with Xfce or other lightweight DEs (so no Gnome nor Unity).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/599610/bluetooth-but-paired-but-not-connected/599620?noredirect=1#comment841222_599620  The description is misleading but check it out

Comment: @Jeremy31 That question would require a significant (if not complete) rephrasing to fit the scope of this question...

Comment: Is receive files from bluetooth enabled in personal file sharing?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I'm not using Unity/Gnome (but Xfce instead), and I would rather not install `gnome-bluetooth` (as mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Look at `dpkg -l | grep obex` if there aren't any results go into the software center and search for obex, there should be a result that mentions bluetooth in the description.

I just installed xubuntu-desktop on my 14.04 install and had the same failures you had until I installed that obex package from the software center

Here is the result from `dpkg -l | grep obex`

```
ii  libmulticobex1                              0.23-1.2ubuntu3                                     amd64        multi-protocol cable OBEX library
```

ii  libobexftp0                                 0.23-1.2ubuntu3                                     amd64        object exchange file transfer library

ii  libopenobex1                                1.5-2.1                                             amd64        OBEX protocol library

ii  obex-data-server                            0.4.6-0ubuntu2                                      amd64        D-Bus service for OBEX client and server side functionality

ii  obexd-client                                0.46-1ubuntu7                                       amd64        D-Bus OBEX client

ii  obexftp                                     0.23-1.2ubuntu3                                     amd64        file transfer utility for devices that use the OBEX protocol

Not sure if it will help

Comment: Which package do you mean? I already have `obexpushd` installed, but according to the devels this shouldn't be making any difference...

Comment: I believe it was obextool but you have a slightly different version of blueman

Comment: From what I see, `obextool` is not a dependency of `blueman`...